# Joomla, Breezing Forms, QuickMode Form second upload doesn't work

Tags: uploading, breezingforms

In my form I added two "file upload" elements. Both those elements have permission to upload only one file since information about those files are after form submition are inserted into table. These elements are copy of one another and the only difference is the name.

First file is uploaded successfully and I receive info about it in email, and it's really in folder. Second file is in folder, but filename is incorect, instead of HR_logo.jpg, there is `HR_logo.jpg_upload_image_847239430f4e163a379639c7c49422c0_d775f9e424dc81ac736b20294eda1559_flashtmp` file
which is identical to "real" (HR_logo.jpg) file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: !!!! And files are less than 100KB, so filesize is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

When  I disabled "Use Flash upload" checkboxes for both uploads, I never again encountered that problem.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your field name doesn't contain underscores, then you can use the flashuploader.